# SVG element not clicked manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg

All html element manually click but why not svg element by **.click()** method. any help appreciated

```
ellipse[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("ellipse");
});
ellipse[0].click();
```

see this link : https://plnkr.co/edit/nVb6p7PD6nvuVsDhYcNU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

They are different because the specifications that define them say different things.

The HTML specification says that HTML elements have a [click method](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361).

The SVG specification does not say that SVG elements have a [click method](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGElement).

SVG and HTML don't always work the same way.

Comment: thanks for answer. can u have any other method for manually click of SVG element?

Comment: Why would you need to? Write your click code as a function then call the function when you want rather than faking a click to indirectly call the function.

Comment: but is use **this** object.

Comment: so I not call function direct... Means when I click an ellipsis then it trigger click another image...

Comment: have the ellipsis click do whatever you would do on the image click, i.e. take the same action.

Comment: hmmm. check https://sandeep.itch.io/wagh-bakri. I need if any item in ellipsis then click into ellipsis then also click on item

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `click()` on the element, just call the function that handles the click.  For example:

```
function handleH1Click() {
  alert("H1");
}

h1.addEventListener("click", handleH1Click);

ellipse.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("ellipse");
  handleH!Click();
});
```